# tableview won't update automaticaly when new item is added

Tags: java, javafx

When a new announcement is created, the tableview doesnt refresh, why?

Here is my code, it works when I use tabelview.refresh(), but I don't think that is the best solution. I thought that with the use of an ObservableList, the tableview would update when the list was changed.

```
package GUI;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;

import domein.Aankondiging;
import domein.DomeinController;
import domein.Sessie;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class BeherenAankondigingenSchermController extends VBox {
    @FXML
    private Label infoLabel;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Aankondiging> tableviewSessie;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Aankondiging, String> publicatiedatumTableColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Aankondiging, String> publicistTableColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Aankondiging, String> inhoudTableColumn;
    @FXML
    private Button nieuweAankondigingPlaatsenButton;
    @FXML
    private Label tekstAankondigingLabel;
    @FXML
    private TextArea tekstAankondigingTextArea;
    @FXML
    private Label foutmeldingLabel;
    @FXML
    private Button aankondigingPlaatsenButton;

    private DomeinController dc;
    private Sessie sessie;

    private ObservableList<Aankondiging> aankondigingen;

    public BeherenAankondigingenSchermController(DomeinController dc, Sessie sessie) {
        this.dc = dc;
        this.sessie = sessie;
        //this.aankondigingen = FXCollections.observableList(sessie.getAankondigingLijst());

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("BeherenAankondigingenScherm.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        build();
    }

    private void build() {
        infoLabel.setText("Aankondigingen voor de sessie " + sessie.getNaamSessie());
        foutmeldingLabel.setText("");

        // items om nieuwe aankondigen te plaatsen onzichtbaar maken
        tekstAankondigingLabel.setVisible(false);
        tekstAankondigingTextArea.setVisible(false);
        aankondigingPlaatsenButton.setVisible(false);
        foutmeldingLabel.setVisible(false);

        // Juiste gegevens toevoegen aan het scherm
        tableviewSessie.setItems(dc.geefAankondigingenVanSessie(sessie));
        //dc.geefAankondigingenVanSessie(sessie)

        // altijd met properties werken!!!!!!!!!!!
        // properties aan de kolommen koppelen
        publicatiedatumTableColumn
                .setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().publicatieDatumAankondigingProperty());

        publicistTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().publicistProperty());

        inhoudTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().InhoudAankondigingProperty());
    }

    @FXML
    void nieuweAankondigingPlaatsenButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        tekstAankondigingLabel.setVisible(true);
        tekstAankondigingTextArea.setVisible(true);
        aankondigingPlaatsenButton.setVisible(true);
        foutmeldingLabel.setVisible(true);
    }

    //aankondiging wordt toevoegd maar is nog niet zichtbaar in tableview
    @FXML
    void aankondigingPlaatsenButtonClicked(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            dc.plaatsAankondiging(LocalDate.now(), dc.getAangemeldeGebruiker().getNaam(), tekstAankondigingTextArea.getText(), sessie);
            tekstAankondigingLabel.setVisible(false);
            tekstAankondigingTextArea.setVisible(false);
            aankondigingPlaatsenButton.setVisible(false);
            foutmeldingLabel.setVisible(false);
            tekstAankondigingTextArea.setText("");
            foutmeldingLabel.setText("");

            //voorlopige oplossing (wss is dit niet de beste...)
            tableviewSessie.refresh();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            foutmeldingLabel.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

```
public ObservableList<Aankondiging> geefAankondigingenVanSessie(Sessie sessie) {
        return FXCollections.observableList(kalender.geefAankondigingLijst(sessie));
    }
```

```
public ObservableList<Aankondiging> geefAankondigingLijst(Sessie sessie) {
        return FXCollections.observableList(sessie.getAankondigingLijst());
    }
```

```
@Override
    public ObservableList<Aankondiging> getAankondigingLijst() {
        return FXCollections.observableList(aankondigingLijst);
    }
```

All this items are saved in a database, my project is to big to paste all the code in here. Can somebody resolve the problem?

Comment: [mcve] please .. and unrelated: a) stick to java naming conventions (your package name violates them) b) favor composition over inheritence (that is _don't_ extend a layout for application reasons and it doesn't enhance layouting functionality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FXCollections.observableList` creates a `ObservableList` that uses the `List` passed as parameter to store the info. This doesn't mean the backing list somehow gains the ability to notify the wrapping list of updates automatically. In fact you do not receive any events, unless you modify the contents of the backing list through the `ObservableList`.

The fact that you're not storing any of the lists except for `aankondigingLijst` (and the list used as `items` which is never retrieved for modification) in a way that allows you to access later to do modifications, indicates that you're never updating any list except for `aankondigingLijst` which does not result updates being triggered for any of the 3 `ObservableList`s that recursively wrap `aankondigingLijst`.

The only way you could receive updates in the scenario you present would be to make `aankondigingLijst` an `ObservableList` itself and never creating an `ObservableList` wrapping the list in the method calls used to retrieve the list used as `items`:

```
public ObservableList<Aankondiging> geefAankondigingenVanSessie(Sessie sessie) {
    return kalender.geefAankondigingLijst(sessie);
}
```

```
public ObservableList<Aankondiging> geefAankondigingLijst(Sessie sessie) {
    return sessie.getAankondigingLijst();
}
```

```
private final ObservableList<Aankondiging> aankondigingLijst = ...; 

@Override
public ObservableList<Aankondiging> getAankondigingLijst() {
    return aankondigingLijst;
}
```